# Get bound item inside click event handler of the GridViewColumn button

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button, data-binding

I'm trying to make an application that shows day of the week and start/end of you working day as an exercise.

So I've made XAML with this elements and bindings:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TimeListView}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Day" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"  />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Time"  
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button x:Name="EditEntry" Content="Edit" Click="EditClick" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
```

and in my EditClick I have this code:

```
private void EditClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sender: " + sender.ToString());
}
```

So my question is: How can I get a hold of the data for date and time in the same row in my EditClick-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [DataContext property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) of the sender button. It will contain the item bound to the [current("parent")](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF) row:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.TimeListView = new ObservableCollection<Item>(new Item[]
        {
            new Item(),
            new Item()
        });

    this.DataContext = this;
}

public ObservableCollection<Item> TimeListView
{
    get;
    private set;
}

private void EditClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    var item = (Item)button.DataContext;

    MessageBox.Show("Item is: " + item.ToString());
}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.Day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        this.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    }

    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}", this.Day, this.Time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if I've interpreted the question right, when the EditClick function is called, you want to get the current selected date and time?

If so, just do:

```
string theCurrentSelectedDateTime = YouListView.ColumnOne.SelectedItem.ToString() + YourListView.ColumnTwo.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

That should get you what you want. But if you were asking about something else, then comment about, because I'm not allowed to comment yet :(.